# Content under the navigation bar when connect my view to a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I added a `UITabBarController`, then manually I added a navigation bar to the `UITabBarController`, so my `UITabBarController` looks like this:

[image]

Then I drag a segue from my `UITabBarController` to two `UITableViewController`.

My problem is that in my `UITableViewController` when I load data, the data comes behide the navigation bar, not under it.

[image]

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be embed in `navigation controller` first then u embed that `navigation controller` with `tabbar controller` then it should work fine

Comment: i have two tabs, each one of them is a ui view controller, which one of them should be embaded in navigation controller ?

Comment: both should be embed in navigation controller then embed both the navigation controller into the tabbar

Comment: then i don't know how to embd both of them, i know how to embd just one, which is by go to editor and then select embd in navigation cotroller. how can i embd both of them please?

Comment: oh i mean if u have 2 VC, it should be embed in 2 navigation controller, then that 2 navigation controller embed into 1 tabbar controller